Fourier Series TRICKY question

if it is a even or an odd function and how to calculate the Fourier series of it?
F(x) = { sin x ; -pie<x<0
-sin x ; 0<x<pie }
need to expand this Fourier series but the limits are tricking us into thinking whether it is odd or even function. can't use any software exam questions

You can use mathjax like this $...$ to format math content like this $\sin(x)$. Other than this, there are  plenty of resources on how to compute Fourier transforms of functions with different properties online, eg. on Wikipedia. Since your function is restricted to a finite domain, it is even more straight forward in this case. Think about the bounds of integration and then proceed from there.

This question is about math, not physics, and does not belong on this site.

Why are you unable to determine whether this function is even, odd, or neither? Why do you think a function must be even or odd in order to have a Fourier series?

pie The Greek word for $\pi$ is “pi”.
